# is it possible to make debugger like ollydbg via c#?

Tags: c#, debugging, ida, ollydbg

Is it possible to make a debugger like OllyDbg using C# ? I mean debug VC++, Delphi, Borland? Or make something like IDA (debugger) ?

Comment: The only thing you can't do, as far as I know, is make kernel stuff, as the .NET framework is not available at that level. For the rest, only your skill and time are a limiting factor.

Comment: @MicroVirus  ty very much :) ♥♥♥

Comment: @MicroVirus, you better answer saying: the only think you can do is the UI. A debugger like OllyDbg without any KERNEL or CPU function is not a debugger anyway... See my comments below and show me how access CPU and STACK registers using ONLY .NET.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No.

.NET Framework languages as C# and VB.NET are not the best choice to conduct it. You will have a LOT of work to get information from CPU, libraries and so forth. You will must to implement so many procedures to direct-call DLL´s and hardware, that it could be impossible in some scenarios.

To make a debug and get Ring-0 and other CPU and OS features, should be better to utilize C, C++ or even pure Assembly.

Comment: I agree with the bulk of your text, but the 'No' is just not true.

Comment: @MicroVirus, how get CPU-Register and Stack-Register info and, in other way, how set INT5 or RING-0 step using ONLY .NET?  It´s simply IMPOSSIBLE!  You will have to access other native-code libraries to get these information (if possible without change the debbugged registers!). So, I continue thinking about lack of performance and a lot of code and link among libraries, all of them, uneccessary if doing the entore job in ASM or C/C++.

Comment: I really can't understand these stupidly down votes in stackoverflow. always users with high scores give other users down votes!